# Ajax Post web api model null

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I saw o lot of this questions here and i tried everything but still dont work, so this is my last try

this is my js:

```
    var test = { backlog: "backlog", todo: "todo", done: "done"};
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({ data: test }),
    url: "Post",
    contentType: 'application/json'
    }).done(function (res) {
     console.log('done' , res);
    });
```

my controller: testt is null.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public test Post([FromBody] test testt)
    {
        test data = testt

        return data;
    }
```

my model:

```
public class test
{
    public test(){}
    public string backlog { get; set; }
    public string todo { get; set; }
    public string done { get; set; }
}
```

the problem is i send the data to the server but the json dont bind with the model

if i use this :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public test Post([FromBody] JObject testt)
    {
        test data = testt["data"].ToObject<test>();

        return data;
    }
```

will work but i dont want to do this i want the automatic bind cuz will be much much easier with complex data.
i'm sorry for duplicate but i dont know what to do anymore.

Comment: Its just `data: JSON.stringify(test),` (alternatively, the method would be `public test Post([FromBody] test data)` if you use `data: JSON.stringify({ data: test }),`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes this was a part of the problem thank you very much, but i dindt show my data to you and in my real data theres a list<> when i try to use list<otherModel> the test become null, if i use list<object> i get a string and all run i still want to make work as a list<otherModel> but thanks i'm new with this and what you said was right.

Comment: If its an array - e.g. `var test=[{ backlog: "a", todo: "b", done: "c" }, { backlog: "x", todo: "y", done: "z" }];`, then it will work fine using `data: JSON.stringify({ data: test })` (or just `data: JSON.stringify(test)`) and the method has a parameter `List<test> data` - but you need to show your real code if you are still having problems

Comment: Hello again. I found the problem, actually was more two problems 1° my data had a list of list of a model, so only list<model> it did not work, 2° some arrays in my data was empty so he stop to populate the fields and return the object null, to fix this i initializate the list in the construct.
Do you have any tips for doing this better or initializing the list on the construct its ok?
thanks for you time again.